# Excel Linked Server in SQL Server 2008 R2 OLEDB error

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have set up a linked server from SQL Server 2008 R2 to an Excel spreadsheet, from which I read the contents in to a table, for comparison during an import.

The spreadsheet is held on a network share from an application server.

Basically, this works perfectly on the SQL Server when I run:

```
SELECT * FROM SpreadsheetLink...[CONTENTS$]
```

However, as I now need to schedule this, I need to create an SSIS package on the application server, which runs the same query.

So now, whenever I try to do this though (either by writing the script in to SSIS or by logging in to SQL Server Mgmt Studio on the App server and then opening an SQL connection to the SQL Server and querying directly) I get an error:

> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "SpreadsheetLink" reported an error.  The provider did not give any information about the error.
>
> Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "SpreadsheetLink"

I first wondered whether I had forgotten to install OLEDB12.0 on the application server, but it is there.

I next wondered whether it was a permissions issue, so I added the EVERYONE group, with "Full Control" to the folder containing the spreadsheet and also ensured that the account that I am both logged in with and running the query as is an administrator on both the SQL server and the Application Server.

I also checked that the account was a member of the Distributed COM user group on both servers (it was).

---

Additional info:

I have tried several things, but it still fails.

I added the following

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
```

I then re-tested, but got the same results (success from the local SQL server, failure from the other server).

Next, I tried creating a different query, referring to the spreadsheet directly by path, rather than by Link-name, but that resulted in exactly the same outcome:

```
SELECT * INTO TargetTableName FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
                     'Excel 12.0;Database=\\SERVER_NAME\PATH\fileName.xls;HDR=YES',
                     'SELECT * FROM [sheetName$]')
```

I also applied all of the suggestions in the following page:
http://visakhm.blogspot.co.uk/2013/12/how-to-solve-microsoftaceoledb120-error.html. But still no joy.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit...  When you successfullt run the query, what machine are you on?  You mention an "App server"  Where does this fit into the picture?  Is it a separate machine running SSIS?

Comment: Hi DZ.  
Yes, the App Server is a separate server which is used for the running of SSIS packages (basically, because the SAP Application that controls most of these tasks resides on that server).  I can successfully run the script directly from the SQL server, but cannot include the same command either in a DTSX package on the App Server. Nor can I even run the same query in SQL Server Mgmt Studio on the App Server and connected to the SQL box.

Comment: Okay, a couple more things to try out...  Connect to the SSIS Server and manually launch the package.  What were the results?  Then connect to the SQL server and create an SQL Agent job to launch the package.  What are those results?  If neither of those worked, copy the Excel file to the SQL server and try both again.  If you got this to work once, it must be some sort of security thing.  The trick is to find out where.